# Why can't I split the calendar year into 10-day increments correctly?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, series

I have the following code that splits the calendar year into 10-day increments in which the first ten-day increment should be a "1", the next 10-day increment, "2", etc.

For some reason I only have nine "1s" whereas there should be ten. Could someone help me with this?

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

datetimes = np.arange(
    datetime(2018,1,1), datetime(2019,1,1), timedelta(days=1)
    ).astype(datetime)

np.array([datetime.timetuple().tm_yday//10+1 for datetime in datetimes])
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an array that starts from the 1 January and it increments 10 days till year ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `tm_yday` starts with `1` and not `0`.

You should use this if you want to start counting from `1`:

```py
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

datetimes = np.arange(
    datetime(2018,1,1), datetime(2019,1,1), timedelta(days=1)
).astype(datetime)

np.array([(datetime_.timetuple().tm_yday - 1)//10+1 for datetime_ in datetimes])
```